# cant fetch the previous 5 values in Firestore (I read the documentation but it is still really confusing)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I need to fetch the previous 5 value when clicked on the previous button, in the current project I am using Firestore, recoil, react and material UI, below is the code I came up with upon looking up tutorials.

sensor component :

```js
const itemsPerPage = 5; // basically page size


React.useEffect(() => {
  let isMounted = true;
  setLoading(true);
    
  const initialPageQuery = query(
      collection(db, ENV, VERSION, "facilities", facilityId, "sensors"),
      where("active", "==", true),
      orderBy("active"),
      limit(itemsPerPage)
  );
    
  getDocs(initialPageQuery)
      .then(querySnapshot => {
              setLoading(false);
              const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));
              setSensors(data);
    
              // Set both firstDoc and lastDoc after fetching initial data
              const firstDoc = querySnapshot.docs[0];
              const lastDoc = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];
              setFirstDoc(firstDoc);
              setLastDoc(lastDoc);
          })
      .catch(error => {
            setLoading(false);
            console.error(error);
      });
    
      return () => {
          isMounted = false;
      };
  }, [facilityId]);

// Function to fetch more data when the "Load More" button is clicked
const fetchMoreData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    // Query Firestore for the next page using the last document as the starting point
    const nextPageQuery = query(
            collection(db, ENV, VERSION, "facilities", facilityId, "sensors"),
            where("active", "==", true),
            orderBy("active"),
            startAfter(lastDoc),
            limit(itemsPerPage)
        );

    try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(nextPageQuery);
        const newData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));

        // Replace the existing data with the new data
        setSensors(newData);

        // Update the last document for the next fetch
        const lastDoc = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];
        setLastDoc(lastDoc);
        setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
        setLoading(false);
        console.error(error);
    }
};

const fetchprev = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    
    const prevPageQuery = query(
            collection(db, ENV, VERSION, "facilities", facilityId, "sensors"),
            where("active", "==", true),
            orderBy("active"),
            endBefore(firstDoc), // Use firstDoc as the parameter
            limit(itemsPerPage)
    );
    
    console.log("Fetching previous page...");
    
    try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(prevPageQuery);
        const prevData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));
    
        console.log("Previous data:", prevData);
    
        // Update firstDoc for the next fetch
        if (querySnapshot.docs.length > 0) {
            const firstDoc = querySnapshot.docs - prevData;
            console.log("First document after fetch:", firstDoc);
            setFirstDoc(firstDoc);
        }
    
        setSensors(prevData);
        setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
        setLoading(false);
        console.error("Error fetching previous data:", error);
    }
};
```

I just tried adding the last page as the ref to the cursor in order to use it with the  endBefore method provided by Firebase but still it cant fetch the values, going forward and fetching the next 5 entries is not an issue.

Comment: Are there any exceptions in your browser's JS Console ?

Comment: @GregFenton no everything is fine except the MUI fragment error which I dont think is the root cause for anything

Comment: What are you getting as a result set when you call `fetchprev()`?  What values come in from Firestore?

Comment: well it says ` main.67108de63d519c115e85.hot-update.js:131 Cannot fetch previous data: 'firstDoc' is not initialised.` when I click back after clicking next and retrieving the next 3 values.

Comment: So....what is the value of `firstDoc` when `fetchprev()` runs?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `limitToLast(itemsPerPage)` instead of `limit(itemsPerPage)` when paginating backwards.

Comment: you mean limitToLast right? I kinda tried that still just doesn't work and the same result.

Comment: `limit` and `limitToLast` will **not** give the same results (unless there are no more than the `itemsPerPage` documents), so you'll want to check if that's really the code that is being executed